How to call C macro from V/Vlang when macro declares a variable
I am trying to use flecs from V. The flecs header file defines a C macro (ECS_COMPONENT) that in turn defines a new C identifier/variable when expanded.
I've abstracted the problem into a minimal example with my custom code and C macro:
c/myc.h:
#define DEFINE_IT(k, v) int k = v;

src/main.v:
#flag -I @VMODROOT/c
#include "myc.h"

fn C.DEFINE_IT(any, int)

fn main() {
  C.DEFINE_IT(my_c_var, 123)
}

The V compiler complains:
src/main.v:36:14: error: undefined ident: `my_c_var`

which makes sense of course.
Trying to define my_c_var as a V identifier beforehand does not work either:
src/main.v:
...
  my_c_var := 0
  C.DEFINE_IT(my_c_var, 123)
...

as the C compiler is now unhappy (of course):
================== C compilation error (from tcc): ==============
cc: /tmp/v_1000/vtest01.01J38NM2KK860J55336ZC4N3X6.tmp.c:18801: error: redeclaration of 'my_c_var'

So I'm wondering how I can call a C macro that declares/defines new identifiers from within V.

EDIT: I've been looking into how other languages do this kind of thing, and for Zig, I've seen that this specific use case is actually not supported. So, chances are that this maybe can neither be done in V? Thus, I would instead have to write small functions of C code that "call" that ECS_COMPONENT macro and then call those C functions from V? That'd be a workaround, but somewhat unsatisfying.
